Index reliability/source for yahoo finance
I had a small question regarding the reliability of the data on Yahoo Finance, I know that this source is full of flaws but it has the enormous advantage of being free.
I had a question regarding the MSCI WORLD Index (^990100-USD-STRD).
Indeed on the MSCI site, I can read that the data before 1995 are calculated monthly, or here on access to daily data until 1972, the existing variations are indeed not simply smoothed over the month.
So I was wondering if anyone knew where this data came from or how it was estimated?
Yahoo finance says: "Historical world index data provided by Commodity Systems, Inc." but I see start date= 2012-09-10 for msci world on their site
Thanks !
